# Including more than one word variables when using it in a function

Tags: r

I'm trying to make a basic function that takes zipcode and outputs a bar chart of the cases in the zip code. It works pretty well for one-word counties (e.g. Jefferson county), but not two-word counties (e.g. St. Clair county). How do I fix this?

```
library(httr) 
url <- "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/scpike/us-state-county-zip/master/geo-data.csv"
zipcodeData <- content(GET(url), type = 'text/csv')

zipCaseGraph<- function(zip) {
  tbl.county <- subset(zipcodeData, zipcode == zip) 
  countyZip<- tbl.county$county
  stateZip<- tbl.county$state
  url <- paste0("https://knowi.com/api/data/ipE4xJhLBkn8H8jisFisAdHKvepFR5I4bGzRySZ2aaXlJgie?entityName=County%207%20day%20growth%20rates&exportFormat=csv&c9SqlFilter=select%20*%20where%20County%20like%20", countyZip, "%20County%20AND%20State%20like%20", stateZip)
  tbl.countyStats <- content(GET(url), type = 'text/csv')
  tbl.countyCases <- subset(tbl.countyStats, Type!="Deaths") #only has cases not death stats
  tbl.countyCases <- tbl.countyCases[seq(dim(tbl.countyCases)[1],1),] #flip row order so that stats start from earliest date and ends with latest date
  barplot(tbl.countyCases$"7_day_count", main=sprintf("Weekly COVID-19 Case Count in %s County", countyZip), 
          xlab="Weeks since 1/29/20", ylab="Weekly Infection Count")
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace the whitespace(s) in the URL with `%20`:

```r
suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(httr))
url <- "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/scpike/us-state-county-zip/master/geo-data.csv"
zipcodeData <- content(GET(url), type = 'text/csv')

zipCaseGraph<- function(zip) {
    tbl.county <- subset(zipcodeData, zipcode == zip) 
    countyZip <- tbl.county$county
    stateZip <- tbl.county$state
    stateAbbr <- tbl.county$state_abbr
    url <- paste0("https://knowi.com/api/data/ipE4xJhLBkn8H8jisFisAdHKvep",
                  "FR5I4bGzRySZ2aaXlJgie?entityName=County%207%20day%20growth",
                  "%20rates&exportFormat=csv&c9SqlFilter=select%20*%20where",
                  "%20County%20like%20", 
                  gsub(" " , "%20", countyZip), 
                  "%20County%20AND%20State%20like%20", 
                  gsub(" " , "%20", stateZip))
    tbl.countyStats <- content(GET(url), type = 'text/csv')
    tbl.countyCases <- subset(tbl.countyStats, Type!="Deaths") #only has cases not death stats
    tbl.countyCases <- tbl.countyCases[seq(dim(tbl.countyCases)[1],1),] #flip row order so that stats start from earliest date and ends with latest date
    barplot(tbl.countyCases$"7_day_count", 
        main=sprintf("Weekly COVID-19 Case Count in %s, %s", countyZip, stateAbbr), 
        xlab="Weeks since 1/29/20", ylab="Weekly Infection Count")
}

zipCaseGraph("08243")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-08-12 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: If I wanted to make unit tests for this function, what would that look like?

Comment: This is a different question, which you should post as such.